# GPU or PSU is making a metallic whirring sound when I launch a game

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, gpu

When I open up a game my computer starts to make a weird sound even if I'm just on the title screen, I'm not sure if it's the GPU or the PSU. I suspect the PSU doesn't put out enough power for my computer, but I have no way of knowing.

Specs:

- CPU: Intel Core i5-4430
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce 970
- PSU: Corsair cx500
- mobo: ASUS h81m-plus

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I have a 120GB SSD and a 1TB HDD, Zalman z11 case with stock fans and a Cooler Master heatsink on my CPU.

The noise has only started recently, and all of these parts are new.

Comment: Sounds like you have a defective fan on your GPU. If it was a power supply problem the system likely would just turn itself off. You claim there is no way to determine if your power supply is providing enough power, actually there is, determine the maximum amount of power your system needs and if its more than 500 watts you should replace the power supply. The suggested minimum power supply for your GPU is 500 watts.

Answer (score 0):

When you start a 3D application (most modern games) the graphics card need to work harder compared to 2D (desktop). The result is that both the PSU and GPU becomes warmer and if the component has a temp controlled fan, it will spin faster to combat the rising temperature.

Since the GPU becomes a lot warmer compared to the PSU, its likely the cause of the annoying sound. You can easily test this by placing your finger at the middle of the GPU fan (don't insert it into the blades, it can damage the fan and hurt your finger) also be gentle (don't damage the fan) when you place your finger at the middle of the fan so that it slows down and then stops. If the sound goes away then its that fan that is the cause. If the sound remains then its likely another fan and you can test them the same way as long as you can reach and place your finger at the middle of it. Do *NOT* open the PSU and put your fingers anywhere inside there.

Once you have identified the faulty fan, return it to the place of purchace for a replacement if you have warranty. Otherwise you may need to look at a replacement solution. If its a custom fan/cooling solution like for GPU or chipset on motherboard then they will most likely replace the whole product (if in warranty). Out of warranty a 3'rd party solution is almost always needed.

Answer (score -1):

I used to face a similar problem a was sure that it was my GPU and not the PSU.

To identified the problem first power down your system and disconnect all the stock case fan. Now all that is left is the CPU, and GPU.

1. First do a CPU intensive task by using Prime95 you can google it.
2. If not you could use SpeedFan 4.50 to increase the CPU fan by not giving it a full load.
3. For GPU Fan control you could use the MSI afterburn or Evga precision for increasing the FAN Speed and detect the problem.